# How do I "blacklist" a wireless network on my Mac?

Tags: macos, wifi

My home wifi network is password protected, as it should be. My neighbor's is not. Because I have password protected my network, my computer continually joins my neighbors instead of mine. I have moved my network to the top of the list of the "preferred" wireless networks, but if my network is down for whatever reason my computer just re-joins the neighbor's network. I don't want to join my neighbor's network, ever. Is there a way to make it so that my computer will never join a particular network, i.e. "blacklist" it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove it from the list of "Preferred Networks" and it will stop auto-connecting.

- Go to "System Preferences" > "Networks" prefpane.
- Choose "AirPort" (or "WiFi" on Lion) on the left.
- Click the "Advanced" button.
- In the resulting sheet, choose the "AirPort" (or "WiFi") tab. (It should be the leftmost.)
- Select your neighbor's wifi network in the list and hit the "-" (minus) button.
- Live with joy at never [auto-]connecting there again!

Comment: As an aside, the order the networks are listed in is the order your computer will attempt to connect. If your network is higher than your neighbors, it will prefer yours -- it's not necessary to remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not always true.  I have two wireless networks at my office, the "official" semi-broken one, and an "unofficial" one that some of us put up.  There are also several neighboring networks.  My unofficial network is in my list before the official one, but i often get the official one :(  A real blacklist would be great.

Comment: @DanPritts That would probably be because your Mac saw the "official" network before the "unofficial" one, and connected to it. You'll have to remove the official network to prevent future connections. (As an aside: what would a blacklist do that removing the network doesn't?)

Comment: I agree that that's why it's happening.  I know that it's reappeared after I removed it with the method you describe.  That said,  I can't say definitively that I never again approved connecting to the "official" network, which would put it back on my approved list.  To answer your question, then, a blacklist would have it never show up under the available networks tab when the mac first tried to connect.

Comment: This is not a good solution: if you have an iPhone that shares the same keychain, but want it to connect to that network, it will be removed as well.

Comment: This solution does not work for me in macOS Sierra (10.12.6). My Mac continues to connect to the unprotected network even though I have removed it from the "Networks" list.

Comment: Agree with @Thomas.  What is the solution when using iCloud Keychain and you still *want* your iPhone to have access?